# ISecurityInformation "Show advanced permissions" link

Tags: c++, windows, security, permissions, com

The `ISecurityInformation` interface can be used to display permissions for:

- an object,
- a group, or
- a user name.

If the `SI_ADVANCED` flag is set when calling `GetObjectInformation`, the **Advanced** button becomes available.

After clicking **Advanced**:

- a **Principal** can be selected
- and then the **View** or **Edit** buttons become available (also contingent on the flags set when `GetObjectInformation` is called).

Clicking Edit or View will bring up the Permission Entry dialog.  On this dialog there is another link that says **Show advanced permissions**.

Regardless of the flag combination that I set when initializing `dwFlags`, I am unable to get anything to display on the second Advanced permissions dialog.

To see the information that I am attempting to glean, right-click on any file in Windows Explorer then select

- Properties

  - Security

    - Advanced

      - *[any Principal]*

        - View

          - Show advanced permissions.

I am trying to gain access to this same information from within my implementation of `ISecurityInformation`.  I have tried just about every flag listed in the documentation of the [`SI_OBJECT_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379605(v=vs.85).aspx), and various combinations, with no success. Changing these flags does alter the layout of the Permission Entry dialog but the actual content of the Advanced permissions area is always blank.

Is there something else that I need to initialize when instantiating the `ISecurityInformation` interface?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by updating the implementation of GetAccessRights as shown at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10811/The-Windows-Access-Control-Model-Part.  The problem lied with the implementation of GetAccessRights, not GetObjectInformation.